# Qt Creator как писать камментарий?

Tags: qtcreator, doxygen

Как только не пребывал писать комментарий все равно всплывающую подсказку получить не получилось максимум что выводит это первый комментарий при выборе авто заполнения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//! пренаправления потока вывода от QDebug в файл log.txt.
void MessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg);
```

Можно ли сделать чтобы qt creator выводил сообщения что то вроде этого ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, что QtC пользуется отдельно генерируемыми файлами с документацией из комментариев, а не самими комментариями, так что скорее всего нет. [Аналогичный вопрос на en.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489969/2076787).

Comment: Можно ли тогда как ни будь автоматически генерировать при сборке файл документации и подключать его к QTCreator?

Comment: По ссылке же есть грубо сбацанный скриптик, который добавляет соответствующие маркировки в Doxygen. Неизвестно, правда, работает ли он, и если да, то насколько хорошо.